# React Hot Loader seems to work but doesn't update. [babel-preset-env]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-hot-loader

I tried to set up a minimal project which utilises the newest versions of Webpack, React, Babel and React Hot Loader.
I have the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772325/react-hot-loader-checking-correctly-but-not-updating). However the only difference is that I am using *(beside solely the stuff mentioned above)* `babel-preset-env` instead of `babel-preset-es2015`, thus the fix does not apply for me.

In short: Everything works, React Hot Loader detects changes but the components are not rerendered and the changes are not applied to the website.

[You can find the complete project here.](https://github.com/PeterKey/minimal-react) (yarn install/yarn start should get it started) You can reproduce the behaviour by changing the `testString` in `/components/App.js` and saving the file.

What am I doing wrong?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules)/,
              use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
              }
            }
          ]
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
      ]

}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
      "react",
      [ "env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 10%"
        }
      }]
    ],
    "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
  }
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import App from '../components/App'

const render = Component => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <Component />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('app'),
    )
  }

render(App)

if (module.hot) {
const NextApp = require('../components/App').default
module.hot.accept('../components/App', () => { render(NextApp) })
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "minimal-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "minimal react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/PeterKey/minimal-react.git",
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --config ./webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I realised that I simply need to set the {"modules": false} property for the "env" preset the same way as for the "es2015" preset.

**.babelrc**

```
{
"presets": [
  "react",
  [ "env", {
    "modules": false,
    "targets": {
      "browsers": "> 10%"
    }
  }]
],
"plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
```

}